# PIVOT IN MULTIPLE SQL SERVER COLUMNS

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the followin data table:

```
CLIENT  ART  MONTH1  MONTH2  MONTH3
  11     1     100     150     300
  11     2     200     250     350
```

But I need this

```
CLIENT  ART  MONTH1  MONTH2  MONTH3  ART2  MONTH1_2  MONTH2_2  MONTH3_2
  11     1     100     150    300      2     200       250       350
```

I have tried this SQL code

```
SELECT cliente, [1] art1, SUM([10]) month1 , SUM([11]) month2, SUM([12]) month3, [10] art2 , SUM([10]) month1_2 , SUM([11]) month2_2, SUM([12]) month3_2
FROM (
    SELECT v.cliente, MONTH(v.fechaemision) Mes, vd.articulo, vd.cantidad
    FROM venta v 
        JOIN ventad vd on v.id=vd.id and v.mov='Estadistica'
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT(
    max(articulo)
    FOR articulo IN ( [100],[1])-- and  Artiulo in ([100])
) AS PivotTable
PIVOT(
    AVG(cantidad)
    FOR Mes IN ( [10],[11],[12])-- and  Artiulo in ([100])
) AS PivotTable
GROUP BY cliente, [10], [1]
```

The result is the following;

```
CLIENT  ART  MONTH1  MONTH2  MONTH3  ART2  MONTH1_2  MONTH2_2  MONTH3_2
  11     1     100     150     300    2      100        150      300
```

I can pivote the arts, but not the quantities in each month of the second art.

Can anyone guide me through the error I'm making please?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [self-join tables](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-self-joins.htm), filtering on `ART` value one less than original table. Add a new self join table for each `ART` item of `CLIENT`

```
SELECT v1.CLIENT, v1.ART, v1.MONTH1, v1.MONTH2, v1.MONTH3, 
       v2.ART As ART_2, v2.MONTH1 As MONTH1_2, v2.MONTH2 As MONTH2_2, 
       v2.MONTH3 As MONTH3_2    
FROM ventad AS v1
INNER JOIN ventad As v2
ON v1.CLIENT = v2.CLIENT
WHERE v1.ART = v2.ART - 1
ORDER BY v1.CLIENT, v1.ART;
```